# Does a 32-bit Linux program's entire runtime lib tree need to be 32-bit?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, 32bit-64bit

On my 64-bit RHEL machine, I'm compiling and running a C & Fortran program that is 32-bit only. It invokes the non-static version of a lot of standard Linux libs (X11, OpenGL/Mesa, Motif, etc...), which of course invoke other libs (libjpeg, libc, etc). Do I have to install the 32-bit versions of that entire devl lib tree in order to build this program validly? And do I have to install the 32-bit versions of that entire run-time lib tree in order to run it without it segfaulting or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can't use 64 bit versions of your libs to run 32 bit software. So yes you need the 32 bit versions.